# How to insert records in different table

Tags: users

```
function lawyer_register_form($form,&$form_submit) 
{
$form = array();
$form['name'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Username',
    '#description' => 'choose a username',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
);

$form['mail'] = array(
    '#title' => 'email',
    '#description' => 'enter a valid email address',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
);

 $form['fname'] = array(
 '#title' => t('Full Name'),
 '#type' => 'textfield',
 '#size' => 20,
 '#maxlength' => 20,
);

 $form['phone_no'] = array(
 '#title' => t('phone_no'),
 '#type' => 'textfield',
 '#description' => t(''),
 '#size' => 20,
 '#maxlength' => 20,
);

$form['street_address'] = array(
'#title' => t('Street Address'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#size' => 50,
'#maxlength' => 100,
);        



$form['county'] = array(
'#title' => t('County'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#autocomplete_path' => 'lawyer_register-autocomplete-engine',
'#size' => 20,
'#maxlength' => 20,
 );       

$form['send_message'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Notify user of new account via email.'),
    '#description' => 'If left unchecked, a message will not be sent.',
    '#default_value' => 1,
 );

 $form['submit'] = array(
  '#value' => 'Submit',
 '#type' => 'submit'
 ); 
 return $form;
 }


 function lawyer_register_form_submit($form, &$form_submit)
 {
 $new_password = user_password();
 $edit = array(
  'name' => $form_submit['values']['name'],
  'pass' => $new_password,
  'mail' => $form_submit['values']['mail'],
  'init' => $form_submit['values']['mail'],
  'status' => 1,
  'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
  ');
   $edita=$edit->uid;
  db_insert('field_data_field_name')
  ->fields(array(
'entity_type' => 'user',
'bundle' => 'user',
'deleted' => 0,
'entity_id' => $edita,
'language' => 'und',
'delta' => 0,
'field_name_value' =>$form_submit['values']['fname'],
))->execute();
   db_insert('field_data_field_county')
->fields(array(
'entity_type' => 'user',
'bundle' => 'user',
'deleted' => 0,
'entity_id' => $edita,
'language' => 'und',
'delta' => 0,
'field_county_value' =>$form_submit['values']['county'],
))
->execute();
    db_insert('field_data_field_address')
->fields(array(
'entity_type' => 'user',
'bundle' => 'user',
'deleted' => 0,
'entity_id' => $edita,
'language' => 'und',
'delta' => 0,
'field_address_value' =>$form_submit['values']['street_address'],
))->execute();
    db_insert('field_data_field_phone_no')
->fields(array(
'entity_type' => 'user',
'bundle' => 'user',
'deleted' => 0,
'entity_id' => $edita,
'language' => 'und',
'delta' => 0,
'field_userphone_value' =>$form_submit['values']['phone_no'],
))->execute();

   user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $edit);
```

I have already created table in database. I want to insert value of

```
fname, street_address, phone_no & county
```

In those table. How is it possible?

I have searched lots of time in google but not getting right answer.

Comment: actually i created custom user registration login form. now i need to add fname, street_address, phone_no & county in to the database.so please help me how i can do.

Answer (score 1):

if you wants to simple insert the field values in a different table you can write insert query in form submit.

```
 function lawyer_register_form($form,&$form_state) 
{
$form = array();
$form['name'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Username',
    '#description' => 'choose a username',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
);

$form['mail'] = array(
    '#title' => 'email',
    '#description' => 'enter a valid email address',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
);

 $form['fname'] = array(
 '#title' => t('Full Name'),
 '#type' => 'textfield',
 '#size' => 20,
 '#maxlength' => 20,
);

 $form['phone_no'] = array(
 '#title' => t('phone_no'),
 '#type' => 'textfield',
 '#description' => t(''),
 '#size' => 20,
 '#maxlength' => 20,
);

$form['street_address'] = array(
'#title' => t('Street Address'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#size' => 50,
'#maxlength' => 100,
);        



$form['county'] = array(
'#title' => t('County'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#autocomplete_path' => 'lawyer_register-autocomplete-engine',
'#size' => 20,
'#maxlength' => 20,
 );       

$form['send_message'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Notify user of new account via email.'),
    '#description' => 'If left unchecked, a message will not be sent.',
    '#default_value' => 1,
 );

 $form['submit'] = array(
  '#value' => 'Submit',
 '#type' => 'submit'
 ); 
 return $form;
 }



    function lawyer_register_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
         {
         $username = $form_state['values']['name'];
         $new_password = user_password();
         $edit = array(
          'name' =>  $form_state['values']['name'],
          'pass' => $new_password,
          'mail' => $form_state['values']['mail'],
          'init' =>  $form_state['values']['mail'],
          'status' => 1,
          'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
          'field_first_fname' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' =>     $form_state['values']['fname']))),
          'field_first_street_address' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' =>  $form_state['values']['street_address']))),
          'field_first_phone_no' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' =>  $form_state['values']['phone_no']))),
          'field_first_county' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' =>  $form_state['values']['county']))),
          );

    user_save(NULL, $edit);
$user_id = db_query("SELECT uid FROM {users} WHERE name = :username", array(':username' => $username))->fetchField();

        $insert = db_insert('table_name') // in which table you want to insert
                  -> fields(array(
                        'uid' => $user_id,
                        'fname' => $form_state['values']['fname'],
                        'country' => $form_state['values']['country'],
                        'phone_no' => $form_state['values']['phone_no'],
                       //write other fields you want to save
                        ))->execute();
                }
```

Comment: all the fields are in diffrent table.

Comment: you wants to insert all the fields value in a single table right?

Comment: No, actually we have created custom user registration login form and insert data in users table. so all other remaining information like fname, phone, street address and county i want to store in 4 different's table

Comment: ok, by using the above query you can save the rest data in a separate table but it is better to create the field here  "admin/config/people/accounts/fields"

Comment: first of all you need to clear about how you want to save the rest field information ? 1.You can create a separate table and save all information in a single table. 2. Create fields "admin/config/people/accounts/fields" and user_save() will save in different table no need to create separate field.

Comment: actually we created two registration form.the standard form for lawyer registration and we sussesfully created field from admin/config/people/accounts/fields" but for second registration we write these code. now i want to store 2nd registration form. users table data are save and created user sussessfully but i want to also store remaining filed.

Comment: You can use profile2 module for multiple user registration.

Comment: No, i read about profile 2.its does not work for my situation.

Comment: have you create any additional table for save data?

Comment: Yes i already create a 4 table to save data.now i just want to insert data into that table.

Comment: Ok, for additional 4 fields you have created 4 table but i want to clear you manually create table in database or by adding fields in drupal site it creates table for you?

Comment: when we create lawyer registration form that time  drupal created that 4 tables now i want to insert same field data into this table.because of additional field in lawyer registration form we created another login form.

Comment: 'field_first_fname' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['fname']))),

Comment: Why you write &$form_submit instated of &$form_state , function lawyer_register_form($form, &$form_state)

Comment: @Swapnil0226 If you have extra information about the issue you need to edit it into the question. Please don't leave it in the comments where it will likely be deleted, and the question will become unclear and useless to future visitors. It's a Q+A site, not support forum, so we need people to stick to the rules. Thanks

Comment: This example helped me

Comment: @pal4life glad to here you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $user = user_load(1); 
    or
 $user = user_load(array('uid' => '1'));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($user);
die();
```

check the fields then save

i think this much code in enough to save fields.

```
function lawyer_register_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
             {
             $username = $form_state['values']['name'];
             $new_password = user_password();
             $edit = array(
              'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
              'pass' => $new_password,
              'mail' => $form_state['values']['mail'],
              'init' => $form_state['values']['mail'],
              'status' => 1,
              'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
              'field_first_fname' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' =>    $form_state['values']['fname']))),
              'field_first_street_address' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['street_address']))),
              'field_first_phone_no' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['phone_no']))),
              'field_first_county' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['county']))),
              );

        user_save(NULL, $edit);
    }
```